How to disable generation of Hibernate Select (find()) Statements on startup of the web application?
I have an web app with: Glassfish/Payara 4, JDK 8, JEE 7, JPA 2.1, Hibernate 4.3.11 (and also Hibernate 5.2.18).
When starting up the web app in Glassfish/Payara Server, Hibernate creates a SELECT statement for all entities mapped to the database. Like this:
select "all fields" from table where pkfield = ?
When monitoring Payara using Visual VM, jmap ou jconsole, I see many of these SELECTs like "char[]" consuming so many RAM heap space.
I don't use this kind of SELECT in my app, I don't call find() method.
I use other ways to find each record from the database in a optimized way.
Is there some Hibernate ou JPA property to configure in persistence.xml to disable the creation of all these SELECTs?
Visual VM Listing with many SELECT
